# ng-bootstrap tooltip arrow is missing

Tags: angular5, ng-bootstrap

I am using angular 5. I am added "ng-bootstrap. arrow is missing.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" placement="right" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</button>
```

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap is installed?

Comment: bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6

Comment: Try upgrading to the current version (4.1.1).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "11.0.0-beta.2"` as per https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#dependencies